# Processing-time temporal join is not supported yet

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am using Flink 1.12.0, and I am reading https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#processing-time-temporal-join. It looks that processing time temporal join is supported.

But, when I run the following application, it complains `Processing-time temporal join is not supported yet`. I am confused about whether it is code error or Flink really doesn't support Processing-time temporal join.

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

    val ddl1 =
      """
      create table s1(
      id STRING,
      tradeDate TIMESTAMP,
      price DOUBLE,
      pt as PROCTIME()
      ) with (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 'D:/T018_LookupJoin_stock.csv',
        'format' = 'csv'
      )
      """.stripMargin(' ')


    tenv.executeSql(ddl1)


    val ddl2 =
      """
      create table s2(
      id STRING primary key not enforced,
      name STRING,
      tradeDate TIMESTAMP
      ) with (
        'connector' = 'filesystem',
        'path' = 'D:/T018_LookupJoin_stocktimechanging.csv',
        'format' = 'csv'
      )
      """.stripMargin(' ')


    tenv.executeSql(ddl2)

    val sql =
      """
      select s1.id ,s1.price, s1.tradeDate, u.name, u.tradeDate
      from s1 join s2 for SYSTEM_TIME as of s1.pt as u
      on s1.id = u.id
      """.stripMargin(' ')

    tenv.sqlQuery(sql).toAppendStream[Row].print()

    env.execute()

  }
```

Comment: I've concluded my answer was incorrect, so I've deleted it. I can see in the code that some processing time joins are supported and others are not, but beyond that I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson. looks my code doesn't have special things compared to the processing time based temporal join with https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#processing-time-temporal-join

Comment: same here with flink1.12.1 and a kafka to s3 join

Comment: @erich looks Flink 1.12 doesn't support Processing-time temporal join. Do you know which version flink supports this?

Comment: im using the 1.15.3 and its working

Comment: thanks @erich for the helpful reply. I haven't tried flink 1.15 yet, one quick question is: can flink 1.15.3 work on java 8? looks that java 11 is needed.